# I am unable to display an ActivityIndicator

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

So this is my code :

```
const imageSource = autoData.imgSource ? autoData.imgSource : autoData.downloadURL;

return (
 <View style={styles.main}>
(!imageSource? <ActivityIndicator size="large" /> :
   <Image source={imageSource} style={styles.image} />
)
</View>
```

So basically I want to display that spinner if there is no info bu I get
 `Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try `braces`.

If your image is uri, you should use it as follows:

```js
<Image
  source={{
    uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/logo-og.png',
  }}
  style={{ width: 400, height: 400 }}
/>
```

Usage

```js
const imageSource = autoData.imgSource ? autoData.imgSource : autoData.downloadURL;

return (
 <View style={styles.main}>
{!imageSource ? (<ActivityIndicator size="large" />) :
   (<Image source={{ uri:imageSource }} style={styles.image} />)
}
</View>
```

Comment: Now just one last thing .. one is a URI and one is a imgSource .. so using `{uri: imageSource}` will only work when the image comes from downloadURL. I need to also display the newly selected image

Comment: You mean you can't see images? Please see my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is related to the image component,

Please try the following,

```
const imageSource = autoData.imgSource ? autoData.imgSource : autoData.downloadURL;

return (
 <View style={styles.main}>
(!imageSource? <ActivityIndicator size="large" /> :
   <Image source={uri:imageSource} style={styles.image} />
)
</View>
```

And this will work only if the 'imageSource' is a uri/url or use directly as above.